# Diagrammatic calcilation of superfluid and normal densities

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

Superfluid $\rho_\mathrm{s}$ and normal $\rho_\mathrm{n}$ densities in a Bose-condensed system can be calculated microscopically from the current-current response function $\chi_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\tau)=-\langle T_\tau j_\alpha(\mathbf{q},\tau)j_\beta(-\mathbf{q},0)\rangle$ as:
$$
\rho_\mathrm{n}=\lim_{q\rightarrow0}\chi_\mathrm{T}(q),\qquad
\rho=\rho_\mathrm{s}+\rho_\mathrm{n}=\lim_{q\rightarrow0}\chi_\mathrm{L}(q),
$$
where $\chi_\mathrm{L}(q)$ and $\chi_\mathrm{T}(q)$ are longitudinal and transverse components of the tensor $\chi_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\omega=0)$.

I tried to calculate $\chi_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\omega)$ from the single-loop diagram and obtained correct result for $\chi_\mathrm{T}$, but $\chi_\mathrm{L}$ turned out to be proportional to $q^2$, so the single-loop result for $\chi_\mathrm{L}$ is incorrect.

In superconductors the similar calculation of electromagnetic response kernel also gives incorrect result for longitudinal part, and including collective excitations is necessary for correct calculations . Is this situation the same for superfluid Bose condensate? Can the correct diagrammatic calculation of $\chi_\mathrm{L}$ for a Bose system be found in a literature?